# Reciprocal space maps units

Tags: diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

I have seen reciprocal space maps in different units.
In some figures, it is represented in delta(l) delta(h) reciprocal space maps units. In some figures it is shown in Q(parallel) and Q(normal) units. Can someone please give me the conversion factor between the two?

Example 1 : [Q space](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v2/n11/fig_tab/ncomms1576_F4.html)

Example 2 : [HL space](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v3/n5/fig_tab/ncomms1821_F2.html)

I have both kinds of figures and need to know how to convert from one to another so that I can compare.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with those map units, but shouldn't you do it with some linear operator to convert between the two representations?

Comment: No... there is a simple relation between the two which I am unable to find out

Comment: This depends on what they are calling parallel and perpendicular but usually the conversion factor is $\pi/a$.